# Sending SMS through SNS with CloudFormation in eu-west-2 region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Why is this resource giving me the error? :

> sms protocol is not a valid protocol

```
"SNSService" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::SNS::Topic",
    "Properties" : {
        "DisplayName": "SNS",
        "Subscription" : [{
            "Endpoint" : "mynumber",
            "Protocol" : "sms"
        }]
   }
}
```

Comment: Just guessing here, but can it be that `SNSService` should be `SMSService`?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. The SNS service provides several protocols, such as email, http, sms and others. The problem is that the eu-west-2 (London) server doesn't support the sms protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently SNS is not ready for the eu-west-2 server, that's the reason.